Server 2012 R2 Printer Default settings not changing, adds untitled
When I change my printer setting in preferences, it starts out as default 2 sided. When I change it to single sided it goes to untitled. I can save a new setting for single sided, but it needs to be selected every time I print. Which makes the setting kind of useless.

How can I change the default setting to be single sided. When I log into the printer via ip The default I see selected there is single side, but that doesnt seem to be reflected in the driver.

When I try to edit default setting as admin on printserver it will not let me here either. Any ideas?

